# Weird journalctl Lines

Tags: logging, log-files, journal

I'm managing my tiny vps and was working on a script to send the logging log to my email. I'm using journalctl to list the logging tentative with:

`journalctl -u sshd >> ./connection.log`

However my log file is simply spammed with line like:

`Mar 10 04:47:31 mydomain.net sshd[31468]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [preauth].`

The IP is not the one of my server. The line with the same IP repeat like 10-20 times. And when someone try to log to my server, it changes to another one until someone log again, etc...

First: Does anybody knows why is a connection close spammed like that ? (I'm new to administrating, and I experiment on my vps)

Second: Is it possible to ignore this lines and not print it in the .log file ? (Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pipe `journalctl` to `grep -v` to remove "Connection closed":

```
journalctl -u sshd | grep -v "Connection closed" >> .connection.log
```